# Error with url.openStream() method when trying to read file from URL

Tags: java, file-handling

**Trying to read a file from URL using URL class and url.openStream()**.

The code:

```
try {
                   URL url = new URL("http://www.puzzlers.org/pub/wordlists/pocket.txt");
                   Scanner s = new Scanner(url.openStream());
                   // read from your scanner
                }
                catch(IOException ex) {
                   // there was some connection problem, or the file did not exist on the server,
                   // or your URL was not in the right format.
                   // think about what to do now, and put it here.
                   ex.printStackTrace(); // for now, simply output it.
                }
```

I get an error saying: The method openStream iusundefined for the DocFlavor.URL.

**What I tried:**

The IDE suggest to change cast which I did
whihc results in:

```
URL url = new URL("http://www.puzzlers.org/pub/wordlists/pocket.txt");
                   Scanner s = new Scanner(((Object) url).openStream());
                   // read from your scanner
```

Still the same error.I also have tried changing Object to URL:

```
URL url = new URL("http://www.puzzlers.org/pub/wordlists/pocket.txt");
                   Scanner s = new Scanner(((URL) url).openStream());
                   // read from your scanner
```

Please assitst and thank you!

Comment: Sounds like you imported the wrong class. Make sure to import `java.net.URL`.

Comment: @Slaw Are you a God? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added `import java.net.URL` and removed all other `.net and URL imports`